# Ansible: uri module ignores status code

Tags: rest, ansible, uri, ansible-2.x

Using the following code to iteratively access a rest endpoint (of artifactory as a matter of fact):

```
- name: create local snapshots repositories
  uri:
    url: "{{ api_endpoint }}/repositories/{{ item }}-local-snapshots"
    method: PUT
    user: 'username'
    password: 'somepass'
    body: "{{ local_snapshots_repo_json|to_json }}"
    force_basic_auth: yes
    body_format: json
    return_content: yes
    status_code: 200, 400
    register: result
    changed_when: result.status == 400
  with_items: "{{ projects }}"
```

However, no matter what I use in the `changed_when` control, the task never causes a change (e.g. `changed_when == 400` or `changed_when != 400` or `changed_when != 'foo'`).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrong indentation.

`changed_when` is a directive defined as a key belonging to the task dictionary, not as an argument to the module action.